# How to use a specific style out of a font-family?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am trying to create my first website and I am experimenting with fonts from fontsquirrel.

The only problem is that I can use only *some* of the fonts I have downloaded through the site.

I am having a great deal of a problem in particular in writing the CSS code correctly, when the font family includes *more than one style*.

Lets take for example the LM Mono 10 Regular and Special Elite for example:

My code for special elite is the following and it works great:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'specialelite';
  src: url('specialelite.eot');
  src: url('specialelite.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('specialelite.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('specialelite.woff') format('woff'),
  url(' specialelite.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url(' specialelite.svg# specialelite') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

and

```
.fifth {font-family: 'specialelite'; font-weight: normal; font-size:  16px; color:black;}
```

This format is easy to work with because the special elite font-family has only one style.

BUT.. When I am trying to adapt this format on a font-family that has more than one styles like for example the LM Mono 10 family, it simply does not work....

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Latin-Modern-Mono

I do not know if the mistake is on the way I am referring to the font family, or if I write the urls wrong... Could you please provide an example of the code in a reply?

Let's say for "Latin Modern Mono Light 10 Regular". How will the font-weight and font-style properties change? I just don't get it...

Answer (score 1):

When I download the resources at the link you provided, it shows each font style as a completely different font family.

This is the Italic version:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'latin_modern_mono10_italic';
    src: url('lmmono10-italic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('lmmono10-italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('lmmono10-italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('lmmono10-italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('lmmono10-italic-webfont.svg#latin_modern_mono10_italic') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

This is the Regular version:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'latin_modern_mono10_regular';
    src: url('lmmono10-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('lmmono10-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('lmmono10-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('lmmono10-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('lmmono10-regular-webfont.svg#latin_modern_mono10_regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

In order to use these fonts as-is, you will need to specify the appropriate `font-family` whenever you use them.

For example:

```
 .fifth {
   font-family: 'latin_modern_mono10_regular';
   font-weight: normal;
   ...
}
```

or

```
.fifth {
   font-family: 'latin_modern_mono10_italic';
   font-weight: normal;
   ...
}
```

Comment: That is a good answer Quantastical. Why have you used "webfont" in there? The special elite font was working without the webfont phrasing.

Comment: ....But it still does not work.... I am losing my mind here... I have the license and the fonts all in the same file with the html/css docs... What is happening here? It feels like a Twilight Zone episode...

Comment: Update the question with your implementation of the fonts that you are experiencing problems with.

Answer (score 0):

For Regular and *Italic* version:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'specialelite';
  src: url('specialelite.eot');
  src: url('specialelite.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('specialelite.woff2') format('woff2'), url('specialelite.woff') format('woff'), url(' specialelite.ttf') format('truetype'), url(' specialelite.svg# specialelite') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'specialelite';
  src: url('specialelite_italic.eot');
  src: url('specialelite_italic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),     url('specialelite_italic.woff2') format('woff2'), url('specialelite_italic.woff') format('woff'), url(' specialelite_italic.ttf') format('truetype'), url(' specialelite_italic.svg# specialelite') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Now, you can use this for Regular: `font-style: normal`

```
.fifth {font-family: 'specialelite'; font-style: normal; font-size:  16px; color:black;}
```

OR this for Italic: `font-style: italic`

```
.fifth {font-family: 'specialelite'; font-style: italic; font-size:  16px; color:black;}
```

Comment: ty naser but I am having problems with the LM family not the special elite ;)